# Создать нетипизированный массив в Си

Tags: c

Всем привет!

Задача: есть динамический массив байтов (byte), пользователь заполняет его с клавиатуры разнотипными данными: целое (int), длинное целое (long), вещественное (double). Перед каждым значением в массив записывается байт с кодом. Перед целым с кодом 1, перед длинным целым с кодом 2, перед вещественным 3. После заполнения массива необходимо на экран вывести сумму байт кодов и саму последовательность разнотипных данных.

Решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char byte;

void my_func()
{
    int N = 10;
    char ch;
    byte *A = (byte*)malloc(N*10*sizeof(byte));
    int *i; long *l; double *d;
    i = (int*)A; l = (long*)A; d = (double*)A;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (k<N)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if (ch == 'i')
        {
            int x;
            byte a = 1;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            *(A + j) = a;
            j += sizeof(byte);
            i = (int*)(A + j);
            *i = x;
            j += sizeof(int);
            count += (int)a;
            k++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'l')
        {
            long y;
            byte a = 2;
            scanf("%ld", &y);
            *(A + j) = a;
            j += sizeof(byte);
            l = (long*)(A + j);
            *l = y;
            j += sizeof(long);
            count += (int)a;
            k++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'd')
        {
            double z;
            byte a = 3;
            scanf("%lf", &z);
            *(A + j) = a;
            j += sizeof(byte);
            d = (double*)(A + j);
            *d = z;
            j += sizeof(double);
            count += (int)a;
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("%c", '\n');
    printf("%d\n", count);
    printf("%c", '\n');
    for (int p = 0; p<j+1; p++)
    {
        if (*(A + p) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", *((byte*)(A + p)));
            printf("%d ", *((int*)(A + p + sizeof(byte))));
            //printf("%c", '\n');
            p += sizeof(int);
        }

        else if (*(A + p) == 2)
        {
            printf("%d ", *((byte*)(A + p)));
            printf("%ld ", *((long*)(A + p + sizeof(byte))));
            //printf("%c", '\n');
            p += sizeof(long);
        }
        else if (*(A + p) == 3)
        {
            printf("%d ", *((byte*)(A + p)));
            printf("%.2lf ", *((double*)(A + p + sizeof(byte))));
            //printf("%c", '\n');
            p += sizeof(double);
        }
    }
    printf("%c", '\n');
}
int main()
{
    my_func();
    //printf("%d %d %d %d", sizeof(byte), sizeof(int*), sizeof(long*), sizeof(double*));

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну ошибка еще на этапе выделения памяти. Мы изначально не можем предсказать необходимый размер массива. А у вас в текущей версии он может сохранить только N байт. + вы не прибавляете смещение для переменной j после записи значения в массив, для каждого типа оно свое.

Ну вот как бы я это сделал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int writeInt(byte * arr,int bytelen,int value)
{
    static int typeSize = sizeof(int);
    arr[bytelen] =  1;
    *(int *)(arr + bytelen + 1)=value;
    return bytelen + 1 + typeSize;
}

int writeLong(byte * arr,int bytelen,long value)
{
    static int typeSize = sizeof(long);
    arr[bytelen] =  2;
    *(long *)(arr + bytelen + 1)=value;
    return bytelen + 1 + typeSize;
}

int writeDouble(byte * arr,int bytelen,double value)
{
    static int typeSize = sizeof(double);
    arr[bytelen] = 3;
    *(double *)(arr + bytelen + 1)=value;   
    return bytelen + 1 + typeSize;
}

void print(byte * arr, int bytelen)
{
    static int intvar=0;
    static double dblvar=0;
    static long lngvar=0;
    int ofset = 0;

    while(ofset<bytelen)
    {
        switch (arr[ofset])
        {
        case 1:
            intvar = *(int*)(arr+(++ofset));
            ofset+=sizeof(int);
            printf("%d\n",intvar);
            break;
        case 2:
            lngvar = *(long*)(arr+(++ofset));
            ofset+=sizeof(long);
            printf("%ld\n",lngvar);
            break;
        case 3:
            dblvar = *(double*)(arr+(++ofset));
            ofset+=sizeof(double);
            printf("%lf\n",dblvar);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    byte arr[10000];
    int bytelen=0;      // длина массива байт
    int N = 3;

    int valType;
    int intvar;
    double dblvar;
    long lngvar;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< N; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&valType);
        switch (valType)
        {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d",&intvar);
            bytelen = writeInt(arr,bytelen,intvar);
            break;
        case 2:
            scanf("%ld",&lngvar);
            bytelen = writeLong(arr,bytelen,lngvar);
            break;
        case 3:
            scanf("%lf",&dblvar);
            bytelen = writeDouble(arr,bytelen,dblvar);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    print(arr,bytelen);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выделение памяти я хочу в конечной версии программы сделать динамическое, и чтобы размерность массива пользователь с клавиатуры задавал. Пока что для теста я N сделал константой. А вот со смещением переменной j действительно затык. Именно в этом ошибка. Но я не знаю как ее смещать. Вы не могли бы подсказать на сколько ее смещать после каждого значения?

Comment: @SergeyZinovev, используйте *sizeof(type)*.

Comment: @АртёмПрокудин, Вы не могли бы помочь найти ошибку в коде? Помочь с реализацией

Comment: дело в том, что для указателей разного типа операция + сдвигает на разное количество байт. (A + 1) передвинет указатель на 1 байт, (d + 1) передвинет его на 8

Comment: сделайте просто через массив юнионов. Это сразу уберет проблему указателей

Comment: @АртёмПрокудин, но в массиве union'ов будут пустоты внутри из-за разных размерностей типов.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь и участие! Задачу решил, доработав свою программу. Решение привел выше.